# How to show Datetime in the flutter local notification?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I'm using the flutter_local_notifications package to show the current date to a notification. I simply get the current date and use it for the notification title and the notification is forever unremovable but I don't know how to update the notification every day without opening the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a repeating alarm and cancel the current notification and create a new one. You can cancel  notification using the following code:

```
// cancel the notification with id value of zero
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(0);
```

Comment: Can I do it without opening the application?

Comment: Yes of course. That's what the alarm is for. When the alarm is triggered, cancel the notification and create a new one